# How can I scrape information from <span> using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm relatively new to coding, looking to scrape information from a webpage that's written inside span but unsure how to do so. Here is an example of the code, the data I'm looking to extract is "Oct 2001 - Jan 2002"

```
<h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>
      <span>Oct 2001 – Jan 2002</span>
    </h4>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The logic ...

```
   elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "pv-entity__date-range.t-14.t-black--light.t-normal"][1]')
```

or

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[contains(@class,'pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal')][1]")
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use that xpath to extract the data by using this code: prev = sel.xpath('.//span[@class = "pv-entity__date-range.t-14.t-black--light.t-normal"][1]').extract_first() - That runs, but when I do print(prev) it returns "None". Do you have any advice?

Comment: have you tried elem.text and change the slice number at the end to [2]. BUT, you can't use extract_first() method and slice index [1], [2]...

Answer (score 0):

To get the span tag of that element.

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h4.pv-entity__date-range.t-14.t-black--light.t-normal>span:nth-child(2)")
print(elem.text)
```